My Vercel API tokens leaked on GitHub. How do I regenerate them?
My Vercel API tokens leaked on GitHub and I'd like to fix the security concern.
Potential solutions:

Fix the issue on GitHub
I could try to create a new, fresh GitHub repository without the leaked API tokens. The issue is my repository has been forked so all the forked repositories will still have my API tokens (reference).

Create a new Vercel account/database
I'm on the free tier of Vercel so I can only have one database, and I don't want to create a new account and migrate all the data. If this is the only way, I'll do it, but I'd prefer another solution.

Refresh the API tokens
If I could just update the API tokens themselves, that would solve my problem most simply. But I haven't been able to find a way to do this anywhere on Vercel without creating a new project, like the earlier solution.



If your tokens are for the Vercel Postgres database, you can regenerate your API tokens.
Navigate to the project, and under Storage -> yourDatabase -> Settings, you're looking for "Reset Credentials."
